# Unable to change the format of a checkbox using CSS

Tags: cognito-forms

What is the CSS selector to be able to change the style in a Cognito form?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

You can use the dev tools to inspect an element, you can then add CSS changes to your own style sheet on your website. The changes will be reflected on your Cognito Form when its embedded on your website.

If you have questions about specific CSS selectors please submit a [Support Ticket](http://help.cognitoforms.com/request-help). We can then provide more detailed information about what you would like to select in the Support Ticket and here.

Comment: Where I can get this dev tools?

Comment: @sam "dev tools" are built into every major browser. Typically, one presses F12 to open them.